# A word/phrase for discussing something not separately but in the course of another debate?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> - There is no separate treatment of this topic but it has been dealt    with ------- other debates.
> - Psychologists have nowhere discussed this issue as a separate subject    but they have been concerned with it -------- other
>     different issues.

What word to put in the above blanks? The above sentences are meant to say that certain topics have been only *secondarily* or *indirectly* discussed, without its independent importance being recognized.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you'd like to change some wording, try, 
   "There is no separate treatment of this topic but it has been brushed upon by other debates"
   If you want to keep the same format, you can say, "There is no separate treatment of this topic but it has been dealt with in part by other debates"
2. Once again, you can try a bit of a wording change here... "Psychologists have nowhere discussed this issue as a separate subject but they have concerned it with other different issues."